# Open file Azure Data Studio with CLI and connect

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-studio

I am trying to start Azure Data Studio(1.46.1) from command line to open a file and connect to server and database. I can get it to work separately:

connect with new query

```
azuredatastudio --server servername --database databasename --authenticationType Integrated
```

open file disconnected

```
azuredatastudio "\\server\share\file.sql"
```

but am unable to open file and connect to server. This will open file but not connect to server and database.

```
azuredatastudio --server servername --database databasename --authenticationType Integrated "\\server\share\file.sql"
```

Is there a way to use [Azure Data Studio CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/command-line?view=sql-server-ver16) to open and connect to database?

Comment: Not sure if this is by design or not but when I try same, ADS creates and opens the connection under `SERVERS` and a disconnected query window for the file.

Comment: and it seems like if ADS is already open and connected to server, running CLI to open file connected to server and database works.